# Unable to get Click event for GMapMarkerCircle in Gmap.net

Tags: c#, winforms, maps, gis, gmap.net

I am using Gmap.net inbuilt class GMapMarkerCircle to show a circle which is denoting polygon's vertex points. I need to provide users with functionality to resize polygon by moving these circular marker points. My problem is that I am not able to get any event for GMapMarkerCircle. I am using the following code so far...

```
        GMapOverlay overlay = new GMapOverlay();
        // Create all circles
        List<PointLatLng> listVertexPoints = Get_VertexPoints(zoneVertex);           
        // Create Polygon
        GMapPolygon zonePolygon;
        zonePolygon = new GMapPolygon(listVertexPoints, zoneName);
        zonePolygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
        zonePolygon.Stroke = new Pen(zoneBoundaryColor, 1);
        zonePolygon.IsFilled = true;
        zonePolygon.IsHitTestVisible = true;
        overlay.Polygons.Add(zonePolygon);
        foreach (PointLatLng vertex in listVertexPoints)
        {
            GMapMarkerCircle circleVertex = new GMapMarkerCircle(vertex, 1, 1, 1, 1, Color.Red, 1);// GMarkerGoogle(vertex, GMarkerGoogleType.blue_pushpin);
            circleVertex.IsVisible = true;
            circleVertex.IsHitTestVisible = true;
            overlay.Markers.Add(circleVertex);
        }
        this.MainMap.Overlays.Add(overlay);
        this.MainMap.Invalidate();
```

Please help me to find the event for these circle markers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which gmap.net nuget package do you use?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I am using Version 1.7.5.0

Comment: Add a rectangle polygone around each marker so you can get mouse events. Or create a class that inherits from google marker to get the event for free. The size of a google marker is fixed though.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what the marker click event is used for. Use this event

```
gMapControl1.OnMarkerClick += new MarkerClick(gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick);

void gMapControl1_OnMarkerClick(GMapMarker item, MouseEventArgs e)
{

}
```

to fire when one of the markers is clicked on. You can then detect the mouse button being held down and use it to drag the marker to a new location.